# How to remove duplicate list from hashmap which is added as values

Tags: java

Below is the program which has hashmap and adding list as keys. However duplicate list are being added. Now i want to remove all the duplicate list inside residing as values.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    Map<String, List<Integer>> sample = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
    List  first = new ArrayList();
    first.add(1);
    first.add(2);
    first.add(3);
    List second = new ArrayList();
    second.add(4);
    second.add(5);
    second.add(6);
    List  third = new ArrayList();
    third.add(1);
    third.add(2);
    third.add(3);
    sample.put("first", first);
    sample.put("second", second);
    sample.put("third", third);
    System.out.print(sample.size()); // Prints 3

    // Need to Remove the duplicate lists
    // Expects two keys with list first and second since third is duplicate value
    // 1,23 and 4,5,6 instead of 1,2,3 4,5,6 and 1,2,3
}
}
```

Comment: so, what if, a list contains `2,3,4,5` and other `3,4,5`. Are you considering them as duplicate ?

Comment: No. It should not have exact values. if it is 2,3,4,5 then the other should not have 2,3,4,5. If the other has 3,4,5 it is considered a different one

Comment: A `Map` will only make sure that the **key** you are trying to add is not already in inside. If you want to consider duplicate values then you will have to remove them manually. Iterating through the map and comparing each entry to all the elements in the set to find your duplicates.

Comment: Is this a [popular homework question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48237181/remove-duplicae-list-saved-as-value-in-a-hashset#48237181)?  I could swear I have seen this before today.

Comment: Falla, that's correct but not sure about the best way to do it. can u pls help with a code snippet?

Comment: The key of the Map is a String, what do you mean by "adding list as keys"? And are you sure this datastructure makes any sense? What should happen with the key of the removed lists - are the key meaningful at all?

Comment: Basically removing the duplicate list and it's key. In the above case key third should be remove with it's value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this piece of code will work for you -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, List<Integer>> sample = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
    List first = new ArrayList();
    first.add(1);
    first.add(2);
    first.add(3);
    List second = new ArrayList();
    second.add(4);
    second.add(5);
    second.add(6);
    List third = new ArrayList();
    third.add(1);
    third.add(2);
    third.add(3);
    sample.put("first", first);
    sample.put("second", second);
    sample.put("third", third);
    removeDuplicates(sample);
    System.out.print(sample.size()); // now it will print 2

}

private static void removeDuplicates(Map<String, List<Integer>> sample) {
    Collection<List<Integer>> list = sample.values();
    for(Iterator<List<Integer>> itr = list.iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
        if(Collections.frequency(list, itr.next())>1) {
            itr.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

This remove duplicate method will remove the duplicate values from the List.